# BufferWidth on Console App - PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to use both the `Console.BufferWidth` and `Console.BufferHeight` method for my Terminal/Console application. I'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.ConsolePal.set_BufferHeight(Int32 value)
   at System.Console.set_BufferHeight(Int32 value)
```

Does this have to do with me programming on a Mac, and that Mac can't support such an action? Or could there be another reason?

Answer (score 0):

To me :

- it seems like a pretty explicit error message; and
- it doesn't surprise me that you cannot assign to that value on the Mac (you cannot under mono, I know).

The one strange thing is that you've reported a message relating to `BufferHeight`, not `BufferWidth`, but I'm guessing you've tried to set both properties.

Comment: Updated the question to involve both the buffer-methods. It's not that explicit, I mean maybe it should refer to the active platform (mac in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You can discover the code that raise PlatformNotSupportedExceptions

- Install the nuget package Microsoft.DotNet.Analyzers.Compatibility

  ```
  Install-Package Microsoft.DotNet.Analyzers.Compatibility -Version 0.2.12-alpha
  ```
- Configure the tool as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/api-analyzer#configuration)
- Select the rule PC001 and select Set Rule Set Severity as error
- When building the project, any issues related to `PlatformNotSupportedExceptions` is displayed as error in Error window

you can code like this for excuting code in windows only:

```
  if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
 {
    Console.BufferHeight = 9999 ;
  // ... More code stuff
 }
```