# Console.BufferHeight in netcoreapp2.1 raise Exception PlatformNotSupportedException in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, console-application, netcoreapp2.1

I have a Console application build in dotnetcorapp2.1. It's running fine on Windows.

When trying to run on Ubuntu it raise an Exception error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
>      at System.ConsolePal.set_BufferHeight(Int32 value)

That is because This line:

```
     Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;
```

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.bufferheight?view=netcore-2.2) didn't mention the limitation that I take into account for  `Console.BufferHeight`

[Googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&channel=crow&q=Console.BufferHeight%20in%20netcoreapp2.1%20raise%20Exception%20PlatformNotSupportedException%20in%20Ubuntu.) didn't help like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262206/how-to-increase-bufferheight-property) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192247/bufferwidth-on-console-app-platformnotsupportedexception?rq=1)

What is the limitation of  `Console.BufferHeight` (and BufferWidth) on  Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this question to [corefx team](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) and submitted an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37579) there.

All credit in this answer go to @danmosemsft

The member `Console.BufferHeight` is not supported on Unix. The docs didn't state the Unix specific behaviors on the Console methods/properties.

The class  `ConsolePal` in the document [ConsolePal.Unix.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/007571b90c3cc555cd30f3b467b87c22f9f665e0/src/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Unix.cs) include also other NotSupported members.

A new [document](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/2433) is created to show the  PlatformNotSupportedExceptions in System.Console

I modified  the code and  catch `PlatformNotSupportedException`  separate and application is running on Ubuntu without a problem.

```
      try
      {
         //.... do your stuff here
      }
      catch (PlatformNotSupportedException )
      {
        //log PlatformNotSupportedException 
        //noop
      }
      catch (exception ex)
      {

         //handle exception
      }
```

**Edit**

**Discovering  the code that raise PlatformNotSupportedExceptions:**

- Install the nuget package `Microsoft.DotNet.Analyzers.Compatibility`

  ```
  Install-Package Microsoft.DotNet.Analyzers.Compatibility -Version 0.2.12-alpha
  ```
- Configure the tool as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/api-analyzer#configuration)
- Select the rule PC001 and select Set Rule Set Severity as error
- When building the project, any issues related to PlatformNotSupportedExceptions is displayed as error in Error window